# Не работает скрипт на элементах, загруженных с бд

Tags: php, javascript, html

С бд загружаю поле:

```
$field = "<li id=\"$id_li\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"checkBox\" id=\"$id_checkbox\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"textbox\" id=\"$id_textbox\" value=\"$text_j\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" id=\"$id_Dbttn\" onclick=\"delete_task()\"></li>";
```

Все id соответствуют нужным id для этих элементов.
Есть функция которая должна удалять эти элементы:

```
function delete_task() {
    //удаление задачи
    var bttn_id = this.id;
    var text_id = bttn_id.replace("Bttn", "Text");
    var check_id = bttn_id.replace("Bttn", "Check");

    var txt = document.getElementById(text_id);
    txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
    var bttn = document.getElementById(bttn_id);
    bttn.parentNode.removeChild(bttn);
    var check = document.getElementById(check_id);
    check.parentNode.removeChild(check);
}
```

Функция работает. Но если я хочу использовать ее на элементе, который я взял с бд, возникает ошибка "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" на этой строке:

```
var bttn_id = this.id;
var text_id = bttn_id.replace("Bttn", "Text");
```

Comment: У Вас в тексте нет элемента с `id`, содержащим "Bttn" ("$id_Dbttn"?), и нет элементов с `id`, отличающимися от "$id_Dbttn" на "Техт" и "Check".

Comment: Вот что сохраняется в бд <li id="Li_id_1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="Check_id_1" onclick="doit()"><input type="text" class="textbox" id="Text_id_1" value="werwerw"><input type="button" value="Delete" id="Bttn_id_1" onclick="delete_task()"></li>

Comment: $id_li и другие - это что, переменные php? Каким они дожны замениться на свои значения в тексте взятом из базы?

Comment: в массиве я передаю Li_id_n, потом заменяю Li на Bttn и другие           $id_li = $arr["li_ids"][$i];
 $id_checkbox = str_replace("Li", "Check", $id_li);

Comment: в бд они заносятся уже в таком виде <li id="Li_id_1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="Check_id_1" onclick="doit()"><input type="text" class="textbox" id="Text_id_1" value="werwerw"><input type="button" value="Delete" id="Bttn_id_1" onclick="delete_task()"></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вызов `delete_task()` в атрибуте `onclick` происходит в глобальном контексте, так что `this` внутри delete_task это `window`, у которого нет свойства `id`.

```
onclick="delete_task.call(this)"
```

Comment: не помогло) хотя я наверное сделал что-то не так)

Comment: @Xenvert - вполне вероятно

Comment: если заменить этим onclick="delete_task.call(this)" то ничего не изменится?

Comment: это вопрос или констатация факта?

Comment: ну там знак вопроса в конце стоит) я заменил, и ничего не изменилось

Comment: $id_li и другие - это что, переменные php? Каким они дожны замениться на свои значения в тексте взятом из базы?

Comment: Убедитесь, что в страницу (браузер) выводится `onclick="delete_task.call(this)"` и добавьте в `delete_task` первой строчкой `alert(this.id);`.

Comment: Заработало) Спасибо большое!)